# save and retrieval picture in sqlite with Qt and Java

Tags: android, c++, qt, sqlite, base64

i want to save picture in sqlite DB and then open that in java android!
in order to save picture i write a C++ program with Qt.
in C++ code i open picture as file, then convert it to QByteArray.

```
QFile file(foodImagePath);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        ShowError("Bad Image File.");
        return;
    }

    QByteArray imageData =  file.readAll();
```

but when i retrieve picture with sqliteManager the output is a bad file.(not correct picture )
then i decide to save picture as a Text in sqlite and convert it to base64 in C++ side!

```
QString(imageData.toBase64())
```

and in android side retrieve whit this code.

```
String imgString = cur.getString(0);

  if( imgString != null) 
 {
         byte[] imgByte = Base64.decode(imgString, Base64.DEFAULT);
         pic =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte,0,imgByte.length);
 }
```

and now the i can see the picture , but it was a little damaged!
[image][image]
can any body help me? PLZ.

Comment: why not save it as a blob instead of a string?

Comment: Much better to simply save a URI to the image (as a string) rather than attempting to save the actual image itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image file is not a text file.
Drop the `QIODevice::Text` flag.

(Using Base64 is not necessary if you handle the blobs correctly.)